# Using portable python to connect to an Access database

Tags: python, database, ms-access, odbc, portability

I am wanting to use portable python 2.7.x to connect to an Access database.  I can't seem to get it working as it doesn't have the pyodbc libraries.  Is there another way to use portable python to connect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newest version of portable python has an option to install pyodbc but you have to select the option it doesn't go in by default.

1. Click on the modules option
2. Select the option for pyodbc

[image: Select pyodbc option from modules list]

Answer (score 1):

I have did it in different way.. .
follow what i have just done on my mac snow leopard!!

Download the the pyodbc's source from where it is on internet. 
Extract and 'cd' into that dir.. . Run '`python setup.py build`' and then take '`pyodbc.so`' file from that build's dir. Make new python file named as '`pyodbc.py`' and write the content given below.(and put that 'pyodbc.so' file with it)

```
def __bootstrap__():
   global __bootstrap__, __loader__, __file__
   import sys, pkg_resources, imp
   __file__ = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__,'pyodbc.so')
   __loader__ = None; del __bootstrap__, __loader__
   imp.load_dynamic(__name__,__file__)
__bootstrap__()
```

(remember put above code in file named as 'pyodbc.py' and put that 'pyodbc.so' file with that)
and at last ..put all these where ever you want to use or in run time add that location into `sys.path` as:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.insert(0,"/my_portable/location") # location to dir which contains those two files
```

after doing all this i have put those two files with my test python file..and in that i am able to import 'pyodbc' without installing it.

```
>>> import pyodbc
>>> dir(pyodbc)
```